# Dynamic Data Slicing tools for Java and C++

Tags: java, c++, c, slice

I am looking for dynamic data slicing tools for Java and C++ that can detect both data and control dependencies in the program. I found out JSlice for Java and none for C/C++.

Are there any other dynamic data slicing tools available for Java/C++/C ?

Comment: Did you find anything interesting?

Comment: Yes. FramaC for 'C' and Codesurfer.